# App.UseSession() vs App.UseAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) vs App.UseCookiePolicy()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, session, session-cookies

As described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#session-state , one can add session to one's web app like so in Start.ConfigureServices

```
    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    });
```

and in Startup.Configure

```
App.UseSession()
```

There is also the possibility to use cookie authentication without identity via the authentication middleware, as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        ...
    });
```

My question is, if I, in Startup.Configure, use both

```
App.UseSession()
App.UseAuthentication()
```

Which Cookie settings will be used? Will the Cookie settings in services.AddSession be completely irrelevant (because the Authentication middleware also uses Session Cookies to keep track of users, right? Or am I completely wrong about that)? Or will they just be two different sessions/services running at the same time?

I am aware that Startup.Configure (the HTTP pipeline) is order-sensitive, as described my Microsoft "Adding the middleware to the app processing pipeline is order sensitive—it only affects downstream components registered in the pipeline." My second question is thus, if I put App.UseCookiePolicy(options) before the above, would it override the settings?

```
App.UseCookiePolicy()
```

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: Session cookie is *not* the same as the auth cookie. They're totally different things.

Comment: Dear Chris, thanks for your answer. So basically, I would have two different cookies running then? Session for storing...session-ish things, and Authentication for all my Claims etc? Would UseCookiePolicy apply for both?